# Convert Redis data to json in Lua

Tags: node.js, lua, redis

I have a redis data whose type is string with format of Json.And, I'm using Nodejs redis.eval function to evaluate the Lua script

```
"{\"hotelId\":100001,\"modifiedAt\":123123112,\"Code\":\"MERC/ENG\",\"available\":true}"
```

redis gives the data to Lua with this form I try to string.gsub() to remove quotation marks but couldn't remove the escape char \ and still it has a string type that I can not achive the object[i].hotelId in loop.Also,Tried to cjson.decode() and encode but it doesn't work or I just coudln't success.Do you have any idea to do that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see your script, but in any case here's an example that will hopefully help you:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> SET foo "{\"hotelId\":100001,\"modifiedAt\":123123112,\"Code\":\"MERC/ENG\",\"available\":true}"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET foo
"{\"hotelId\":100001,\"modifiedAt\":123123112,\"Code\":\"MERC/ENG\",\"available\":true}"
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "local json = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]) local obj = cjson.decode(json) return obj['hotelId']" 1 foo
(integer) 100001
```

Answer (score -2):

Well You could use simple `JSON.parse()` method to convert this string into JSON object,
hope this helps you